# How to specify which ipv6 address avahi service advertises

Tags: ipv6, avahi

I configured a avahi service which I can see with avahi-browse. However I would like to specify which ipv6 address is used in that service advertisement.

I would like it to use "2001:db8:1234:1:594b:8731:6f7e:6f5a" however I don't see a way to specify an address in [avahi.service](https://linux.die.net/man/5/avahi.service) or have the service advertise that service on all ipv6 addresses.

ip -6 a

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
inet6 2001:db8:1234:1::be48:c89c/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 33855sec preferred_lft 33855sec
inet6 2001:db8:1234:1:594b:8731:6f7e:6f5a/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 43190sec preferred_lft 43190sec
inet6 fe80::609b:458e:7bbb:a183/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

avahi-browse

```
=  wlan0 IPv6 fhfs
_broker._tcp   local
hostname = [fhfs.local]
address = [2001:db8:1234:1::be48:c89c]
port = [8883]
txt = []
```

cat /etc/avahi/services/broker.service

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
  <service protocol="ipv6">
    <type>_broker._tcp</type>
    <port>8883</port>
  </service>
</service-group>
```